# Difference between had been and have been

Tags: present-tense, past-perfect

My friend just answered to one of my important questions. Now how should I reply to him?

1.Oh!That question had been on my mind for a long time, finally, I got my answer. ( Oh! I had that question on my mind for a long time, finally, I got my answer)

```
                                   or
```

2.Oh!That question has been on my mind for a long time, finally, I got an answer.( Oh! I have that question on my mind for a long time, finally, I got my answer)

Basically, I am confused with had and have. Since that question is not anymore on my mind after having got an answer, which one of the above two sentences should be used?